# Laravel client authentification with external Laravel passport lumen api

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, lumen, laravel-passport

I have been looking online but i can't find any way of doing it. Let me explain, i have an API (Laravel passport on lumen), i tested it with Postman, i get my access token with oauth, everything is fine. Now i have another Laravel application and i want to know how i can keep all my authentification stuff using the API to login. I have seen lot of apps that actualy retrieve an api_token and they use 'Auth::user()->where('api_token', $token)'. But i find this wrong because i don't want my client to have access to the database, i want every request to the database to be handled by the API. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you using Laravel Password for Authentication API?

Comment: Laravel passport yes, i want to

Comment: Then you will have to define all your route inside api.php route and make http request with something like axios from your front end app.

Comment: Yes i know how to make a request to my passport api and gather stuff. I want to use a login authentification inside my front end app. How can i handle the laravel use session from an external login api

Comment: You're question is not very clear to me .. I'm guessing you're building a SPA .. you have two apps one that runs on lumen and the other runs on Laravel  you want them to exchange data .. my advise to you use Laravel only as API and forget about lumen since it's not really worth it to have different apps with one goal

Comment: My question is very well explained. You have a API, this is the brain of all your company projects. This API will be used by many first parties applications as well as third parties in the future. It doesn't make sense at all to put the API in the same project as a 'first party project'. It needs to be seperated, this is why i used lumen for the fastest way possible. Google does the same thing, they have a central API with SSO and first parties 'gmail,google,drive,cloud,etc'. This is what i want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say you want to login to a laravel backend app via api. make sure you install guzzle.

Route(api): `Route::POST('/login', 'AuthController@login')`

Controller: `AuthController.php`

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

   $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

   try {
    $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 'your client_id',
            'client_secret' => 'your client_secret',
            'username' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            // 'scope' => '',
        ],
    ]);

    return $response->getBody();

    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == 401) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'This action can\'t be perfomed at this time. Please try later.'], $e->getCode());
        } else if ($e->getCode() == 400) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'These credentials do not match our records.'], $e->getCode());
        }

        return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server. Please try letar.', $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

In your front-end app for example vuejs, even laravel using vue component. As you can see, i'm using boostrap-vue but feel free to use the regular html elements

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="login()">
        <b-form-group label="Email">
          <b-input placeholder="E-Mail" class="ml-1" v-model="form.email" type="email" name="email" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('email') }"/>
          <has-error :form="form" field="email"></has-error>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group>
          <div slot="label" class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-end">
            <div>Password</div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-block small">Forgot password?</a>
          </div>
          <b-input v-model="form.password" type="password" name="password" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('password') }" />
            <has-error :form="form" field="password"></has-error>
        </b-form-group>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center m-0">
          <b-check v-model="form.rememberMe" class="m-0">Remember me</b-check>
          <b-btn type="submit" variant="primary">Sign In</b-btn>
        </div>
      </form>
   </div>
  <template>

<script>


export default ({
  name: 'pages-authentication-login-v2',
  metaInfo: {
    title: 'Login'
  },

  state: {
      token: localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
  },

  mutations: {
    login(state, token) {
      state.token = token
    },
  },

  data: () => ({
      form: new Form({
          email: '',
          password: '',
      })
  }),

  methods: {

  login(){
        this.form.post('/api/login')
        .then((response) =>{
            const token = response.data.access_token
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)  
            // console.log(response);
            this.$router.push('/dashboard');
        })

        .catch((error)=>{
            this.$toasted.error('Ooops! Something went wrong', {
                icon : "warning",
                theme: "bubble",
                closeOnSwipe: true,
                position: "top-right",
                duration : 5000,
                singleton: true,
            })
        });
  },

  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i really understand better now. Also, when the login is successfull i see you save the access token for future requests but is the user logged? How do you secure your routes with your guard? How i tell laravel my user is logged in?

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. To tell laravel that the user is logged in, you will have to pass the user access_token to the header of your http request. Since you have the access_token saved on localStorage, you can access and had it to the header. Vuex store will be the best for this kind of scenario. Let me know if you need some guidance for how to make it happen.

Comment: This is exactly what i have some problem to understand. Right now to make it work, when the access_token is retrieved, i get the user and use Auth::login($user). This is wrong i guess since i use the database. I know that when i got the access_token i can use the header and do http requests but how can i tell laravel session i am logged with middleware('auth') for example.